# Page not loading when loaded from an hlink?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a page in javascript and calls a function in his onload, but that didn't called if its loaded from hlink, but call that function if reload the page, any help will be appreciated.

i have a function name loadbody in external Js file here is my function

```
function loadbody(){
  alert("Get values from local storage");
}
```

i write this function in doument.ready() . here is my index page

```
<body onload="loadbody()">
<h1> this is phonegap indexpage </h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried any thing?? It would be easy for all, if you can share the code you tried..

Comment: Any code? Anything to let us know what all you've tried?

Comment: I have the impression that your JS code is wrongly placed in your page. It needs some of the HTML component to be loaded before the JS code can successfully run.

Comment: I guess cache may the cause, you should show the code.

Comment: When you use document.ready(), jquey run code after page load. You call function on page load in html while it not callable!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a onclick event in hlink tag :)

here is your HTML page ::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Js </title>
<script src="script.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1> this is phonegap indexpage </h1>

<a href='http://www.google.com' onclick='loadbody();'>mylink</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is your external JS page ::

```
function loadbody(){
alert("Get values from local storage");
}
```